# Finding the duplicate values between all columns and sort in new column with Pandas?

Tags: pandas, python-3.x

I have this DataFrame:

```
    CL1 CL2 CL3 CL4
0   a   a   b   f
1   b   y   c   d
2   c   x   d   s
3   x   s   x   a
4   s   dx  s   s
5   a   c   d   d
6   s   dx  f   d
7   d   dc  g   g
8   f   x   s   t
9   c   x   a   d
10  x   y   y   a
11  c   a   x   y
12  f   s   d   s
13  d   d   w   a
```

**Intention:**

- With help *Pandas*

1- I wanna search and find the similar values between all columns (CL1-CL4) and sort in a new column (SIM).

2- I wanna find the non-similar values between columns and sort in another column (NON-SIM).

### *What i want*

[image]
How can i do that? With `df.pivot_table` i was not successful.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with similar and non-similar values, which columns do you want to compare? What output do you expect given the input you provided?

Comment: i wanna search and find the similar vlaue (e.g.   'a') in all columns & sort in these similar values in a new columns. and the same for non-similar values.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you would expect?

Comment: The way I understand it now is you want to get the values which occur twice or more in the same row, is this correct? If so, why is the value `'g'` not included in the similar list?

Comment: @Oxbowerce because you cant find 'g' in 'CL1' and 'CL2'. here's the thing: A value is to be added in SIM if are in all columns otherwise is NON-SIM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119133/discussion-between-jsmoka-and-oxbowerce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input data is saved in a variable `df`, I count the values which occur in all 4 unique columns as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

output = (
    df
    .melt()
    .drop_duplicates()
    .groupby("value")
    .agg(count=("value", "count"))
    .reset_index()
)
output["SIM"] = np.where(output["count"] == 4, "SIM", "NON-SIM")
output = output.pivot(columns="similarity", values="value")

print(output)

similarity  NON-SIM SIM
0           NaN     a
1           b       NaN
2           c       NaN
3           NaN     d
4           dc      NaN
5           dx      NaN
6           f       NaN
7           g       NaN
8           NaN     s
9           t       NaN
10          w       NaN
11          x       NaN
12          y       NaN
```

Comment: unfortunatly is not what i want :-(

Answer (score 1):

This may be simpler using sets. Assuming your dataframe is `df`, first get each column's unique values as a set:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
# df = pd.read_clipboard()
cols = df.agg(set)
print(cols)
```

This gives a pandas `Series` of python `set` objects:

```
CL1             {c, s, d, a, x, f, b}
CL2        {c, dc, y, s, d, a, x, dx}
CL3    {c, s, y, d, a, x, g, f, w, b}
CL4             {s, y, d, a, g, t, f}
dtype: object
```

Then you can combine these using `set` operations to get your desired results:

```
sim = reduce(set.intersection, cols)
non_sim = reduce(set.union, cols) - sim
print(sim, non_sim, sep='\n')
```

This gives the results as two `set` objects:

```
{'d', 'a', 's'}
{'c', 'dc', 'y', 'x', 'g', 't', 'f', 'dx', 'w', 'b'}
```

Comment: I receive the error "Set type is unordered" after running! I don't know why

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the results, you may need to make the `set`'s into `list`'s (e.g. using `sorted(sim)`) or pandas `Series` objects. For debugging types of questions, the main [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) site may be better suited than here.

Comment: Actually i want to use it in supervised learning for clustering. This is only a sample of my DataSet. In real is 2e9x3x9. I will that my algorithm recognize correctly the word "Hello World" if see "Hello Worlld"mor "Hellooo WoRld".

Comment: @Jsmoka you should probably post a new question about your larger problem then. (To avoid the ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).)

Comment: Please see this post [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88790/error-set-type-is-unordered-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @Jsmoka I apologize if my previous comment was not clear: Both this question and your new one may be too low level, i.e. about details of your proposed solution. I think you would get better *data science* responses if you pose your high level question, i.e. clustering. (Answers could involve various low-level methods, e.g. [tag:word-embeddings] or [edit-distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levenshtein-distance).)